# Find reference of local variable in vim

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

I am using vim with cscope and ctags. In my earlier editor, I used to find reference of local variables using some key mapped. In vim, using cscope find command, it lists all the variables with same name in other functions too.

Is there any way to list the usage of local variables limited to given scope or function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a generic non-tag dependent way of achieving that in vim called "Goto declaration". Two of the commands that implement this functionality are:

1. `gd` - Goto local declaration.
2. `gD` - Goto global declaration.

These commands depend on the information included in your syntax to determine where the "local" context begins. If that is not included in your syntax then `gd` puts your cursor in the same place as `gD`.

For more information `:help gd` and `:help gD`.

Also, please don't forget that you can go back to where you were before the jump with `''` (`:help m'`).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the things I use [eclim](http://eclim.org) for. The hard work–parsing your code to understand the scope of the variable–is done by the Eclipse IDE, and Vim just asks it for the information. I admit it's like swatting a fly with a brick...but at least the fly ends up smashed, and I haven't really found a satisfactory alternative.